# How to fix : Unsupported Gauge Version(null): This version of Gauge Intellij plugin only works with Gauge version >= 0.9.0

Tags: intellij-idea, gauge

IntelliJ version is 2020.1.2
Gauge pluggin version in intelliJ is 0.3.21
Gauge version: 1.0.7
Commit Hash: ed7b4fd6

### Plugins

html-report (4.0.11)
java (0.7.2)
screenshot (0.0.1)
Getting the following error:
java.lang.Throwable: Unable to parse <C:\Program Files\Gauge\bin\gauge.exe --version --machine-readable> command's output.
error: open C:\Program Files\Gauge\bin\plugins: The system cannot find the file specified.
{
"version": "1.0.7",
"commitHash": "ed7b4fd6",
"plugins": []
}

```
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:146)
at com.thoughtworks.gauge.core.GaugeVersion.getVersion(GaugeVersion.java:44)
at com.thoughtworks.gauge.core.GaugeVersion.<clinit>(GaugeVersion.java:26)
at com.thoughtworks.gauge.GaugeComponent.projectOpened(GaugeComponent.java:30)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed Intellij version to 19.3 release and downloaded external gauge plugin version 0.3.18 which is supported by the IDE to fix the issue.